# Переход к объектам на карте (Конструктор карт Яндекса)

Tags: php, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть БД с адресами организаций, и я хотел бы вставить на страницу сайта ещё и карту. Есть сервис [Конструктор карт Яндекса](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/tools/constructor/).

Вопрос: как через свой сайт ПОДАВАТЬ ему, например, такое

```
"Московская область, город Пушкино, улица ленина 256"
```

а в результате совершать переход туда на карте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ссылка на документацию](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params.xml)

Comment: Плюс еще вот это: [http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geocoding.xml](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geocoding.xml)